# LR(1) parser online verification

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

I'm currently studying LR parsing and in need of an online LR(1) parser to be able to verify my outcome. I've already stumbled upon [this](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/ll-1-parser-generator)(LL(1)), where I was able to verify my first and follow set but I also want to verify my parsing diagram.

Could anyone provide me with a link of such a tool?

For completeness; I need to verify the following grammar:

```
S -> A a
S -> b A c
S -> d c
S -> b d a
A -> d
```

Comment: You could probably make https://zaach.github.io/jison/try/usf/index.html do what you want.

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions of the form "could you find me an *x* that does *y*?". See the help on being [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/rns/176632ab5b2652900871 -- not exactly online, this test script has arguably more features -- warns of inaccessible symbols, handles ambiguity and parses any BNF you can write. Hope it helps. You will need Perl and [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), which provides general BNF parsing. Hope this helps.